# versioned rails db and differ

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, diff

I'm wondering if there's an integrated solution to have a database with versioned records supported by rails (ala version_fu ar_versioned) and a differ thanks!

Comment: Are you looking for more than acts_as_versioned?

Answer (score 1):

Check out [acts_as_versioned](http://wiki.rubyonrails.org/rails/pages/ActsAsVersioned).

Answer (score 1):

Thanks srboisvert for mentioning my fork.  Here's a bit more info/context.  The updated_attributes column's value is set for each version, and lists what attributes were changed from the prior version.  This is useful when you need to display a record/version and want to show what values changed.  I needed this to implement a history view for a particular record we had, where we wanted to color any changed values red in each version we displayed in the history.  This is covered in my blog post which is linked above, along with a couple other minor tweaks.

If anyone tweaks it further, please do send me a pull request, etc.

Answer (score 0):

As you noted, that functionality is supported in plugins, and won't be supported by Rails core.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [forked version of acts-as-versioned](http://codeintensity.blogspot.com/2008/07/fork-of-actsasversioned-to-provide.html) (ar-versioned) that includes an additional column in the versioned table (updated-attributes) that is a hash of what was changed.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using `acts_as_audited` to accomplish this along with the `htmldiff` plugin to get some pretty output.

see: [diff a ruby string or array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/80091/diff-a-ruby-string-or-array/739161#739161)