# comparing two strings in ruby

Tags: ruby

I've just started to learn ruby and this is probably very easy to solve. How do I compare two strings in Ruby?

I've tried the following :

```
puts var1 == var2 //false, should be true (I think)
puts var1.eql?(var2) //false, should be true (I think)
```

When I try to echo them to console so I can compare values visually, I do this :

```
puts var1 //prints "test content" without quotes
puts var2 //prints ["test content"] with quotes and braces
```

Ultimately are these different types of strings of how do I compare these two?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Comparing Strings in Ruby](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/426159/comparing-strings-in-ruby)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From what you printed, it seems `var2` is an array containing one string. Or actually, it appears to hold the result of running `.inspect` on an array containing one string.  It would be helpful to show how you are initializing them.

```
irb(main):005:0* v1 = "test"
=> "test"
irb(main):006:0> v2 = ["test"]
=> ["test"]
irb(main):007:0> v3 = v2.inspect
=> "[\"test\"]"
irb(main):008:0> puts v1,v2,v3
test
test
["test"]
```

Answer (score 109):

Here are some:

```
"Ali".eql? "Ali"
=> true
```

The spaceship (`<=>`) method can be used to compare two strings in relation to their alphabetical ranking. The <=> method returns 0 if the strings are identical, -1 if the left hand string is less than the right hand string, and 1 if it is greater:

```
"Apples" <=> "Apples"
=> 0

"Apples" <=> "Pears"
=> -1

"Pears" <=> "Apples"
=> 1
```

A case insensitive comparison may be performed using the casecmp method which returns the same values as the <=> method described above:

```
"Apples".casecmp "apples"
=> 0
```

Comment: How do we do a comparison by ignoring the case ?

Comment: @stack1 "Apples".to_lower <=> "apples".to_lower

Comment: Will this work with strings like 'a+', 'a', and 'a-'?

Answer (score 7):

`var1` is a regular string, whereas `var2` is an array, this is how you should compare (in this case):

```
puts var1 == var2[0]
```

Comment: or `var2.first` or `var2.shift`.

Comment: If you want to be agnostic on type, `[*var1].join == [*var2].join`

Comment: @histocrat Assuming the array has a single element or you're trying to compare a single string with an array of strings, your comment makes sense. Those aren't very typical operations, though.

Answer (score 6):

Comparison of strings is very easy in Ruby:

```
v1 = "string1"
v2 = "string2"
puts v1 == v2 # prints false
puts "hello"=="there" # prints false
v1 = "string2"
puts v1 == v2 # prints true
```

Make sure your var2 is not an array (which seems to be like)