# how do i compare 2 html pages, and output only the different bits in ruby or PHP?

Tags: php, ruby

how can i get 2 pages, and output the difference between those. getting the pages not a problem, but stuck on how to get the difference....i need a library for ruby OR php

thank you.

Comment: http://linux.die.net/man/1/diff

Comment: possible duplicate of [diff a ruby string or array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/80091/diff-a-ruby-string-or-array)

Answer (score 3):

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.xdiff-string-diff.php

Comment: you might want to tidy them first, if they aren't formatted the same, or have a lot of stuff on one line: http://us3.php.net/manual/en/book.tidy.php

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly what you asked for, but you might find it interesting and/or useful, but there is a [Javascript diff library](http://snowtide.com/jsdifflib) which might work for your needs.

Answer (score 0):

For PHP, I'd suggest looking at the [daisydiff project](http://code.google.com/p/daisydiff/source/browse/trunk/daisydiff-php/HTMLDiff.php?r=113).  This work was done to create a visual diff for Mediawiki.

Otherwise, the easiest thing to do would be to shell out to the diff program, and transform the results into html.