# What is the best Diff library in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, diff

I've looked at diff-lcs ( http://raa.ruby-lang.org/project/diff-lcs ) but it's poorly documented, and appears to be unmaintained.

Are there any good, actively maintained ruby gems for diffing text or html files?

Comment: What do you not like about diff-lcs?

Comment: It's poorly documented, and appears to be unmaintained.  It looks like it could be useful for building a convenient diff library on top of, but I haven't been able to find a way to print a diff of two strings.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I looked around and couldn't find an existing gem or library that offered a convenient way to generate diff style output from ruby.

I just released [diffy](http://github.com/samg/diffy) which does what I want.  It's a lightweight wrapper around `diff` which lets you generate text or html diffs from two strings, without a lot of fuss.  I hope others find it useful.  It's in use on [wiff.me](http://wiff.me) for anyone wants to preview the html output.

Answer (score 6):

I did some very recent searching and discovered that diff-lcs is an actively supported library again.  It is now hosted at [halostatue/diff-lcs](https://github.com/halostatue/diff-lcs) on GitHub.  The recent activity seems to be because one of the authors of [Grit](http://rubygems.org/gems/grit), the object-oriented git library for Ruby, added it as a dependency.  Grit runs [gollom](https://github.com/gollum/gollum), the GitHub wiki system.  If GitHub is a supporter of the library then it's probably safe to say that diff-lcs will remain active for a long time.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about "good"ness, but some places you might go for more information include:

[SO search for "ruby diff"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=ruby+diff)

- [diff a ruby string or array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/80091/diff-a-ruby-string-or-array)
- [Diff two XML doc in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1558613/diff-two-xml-doc-in-ruby)
- [how do i compare 2 html pages, and output only the different bits in ruby or PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1402947/how-do-i-compare-2-html-pages-and-output-only-the-different-bits-in-ruby-or-php)

[Google search for "ruby diff"](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=ruby+diff)

- http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/168365
- http://www.freshports.org/textproc/ruby-diff/