# How do I test XML equality in Ruby?

Tags: xml, ruby, testing

Clearly I need to (a) convert both strings to [canonical XML](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-c14n) or (b) compare their parse-trees.  The following doesn't work because the document object returned doesn't have a sensible `==` defined.

```
Nokogiri.XML(doc_a) == Nokogiri.XML(doc_b)
```

Nor does the following, because Nokogiri's `to_xml` leaves some internal whitespace:

```
Nokogiri.XML(doc_a).to_xml == Nokogiri.XML(doc_b).to_xml
```

This is a reasonable approximation of equality (and will work for most cases), but it's not quite right:

```
Nokogiri.XML(doc_a).to_xml.squeeze(' ') == Nokogiri.XML(doc_b).to_xml.squeeze(' ')
```

I'm already using Nokogiri, so I'd prefer to stick with it, but I'll use whatever library works.

Comment: I'd like to see a good answer to this. AFAIK, canonical XML is your only alternative at this moment.

Comment: possible duplicate of [diff a ruby string or array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/80091/diff-a-ruby-string-or-array)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are looking for structural equality and don't care about the order of tags and attributes, probably the [xml-simple](http://xml-simple.rubyforge.org/) library is a good choice. It converts the xml into ruby's data structures (hashes and lists) which can be safely compared with the `==` operator.

Answer (score 15):

There are actually a couple good Nokogiri-based libraries for checking the equivalence of XML trees, including [equivalent-xml](https://github.com/mbklein/equivalent-xml) or [nokogiri-diff](https://github.com/postmodern/nokogiri-diff), that may be helpful.

I prefer equivalent-xml because it provides a little more flexibility (perhaps at the cost of strictness?), allowing you to compare with or without regard for element order or whitespace.

Comment: Plus that equivalent-xml provides RSpec matchers.

Answer (score 1):

Converting them to strings won't be very successful.  For example, if an element has two attributes, does the order really matter?  In most cases, no.  Does the order of children of a given node?  Depends what you're doing.  But if the answer to one of those questions is "no", then a simple string comparison is a kludge at best.

There isn't anything in Nokogiri to do it for you; you'll have to build it yourself.  Aaron Patterson [discusses some of the issues here](http://rubyforge.org/pipermail/nokogiri-talk/2009-April/000258.html):

> As far as the XML document is
>   concerned, no two nodes are ever
>   equal. Every node in a document is
>   different.  Every node has many
>   attributes to compare:
>
> 1. Is the name the same?
> 2. How about attributes?
> 3. How about the namespace?
> 4. What about number of children?
> 5. Are all the children the same?
> 6. Is it's parent node the same?
> 7. What about it's position relative to sibling nodes?
>
> Think about adding two nodes to the
>   same document.  They can *never* have
>   the same position relative to sibling
>   nodes, therefore two nodes in a
>   document cannot be "equal".
>
> You *can* however compare two
>   different documents.  But you need to
>   answer those 7 questions yourself as
>   you're walking the two trees. Your
>   requirements for sameness may differ
>   from others.

That's your best bet: walk the trees and make those comparisons.

Comment: I'm pretty sure canonical XML (http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-c14n) takes care of all seven of those issues.