# Is there a Ruby equivalent of XMLUnit?

Tags: ruby, xml, jruby, xmlunit

Is there a Ruby equivalent of [XMLUnit](http://xmlunit.sourceforge.net/)?

If not, would running XMLUnit via JRuby be a viable way to use XUnit in a Ruby programme?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope below links may be helpful for you

[Test::Unit::XML](http://testunitxml.rubyforge.org/)

[XmlSimple](http://xml-simple.rubyforge.org/)

[you can find more information with this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1430102/how-do-i-test-xml-equality-in-ruby)