# How to highlighting differences between 2 html files

Tags: html, ruby, file

My web application has job descriptions. These job descriptions can be modified by some users. Each modification result in a new version of the job description.

The content of the job description is edited by the users, in html, directly in the textearea using the tinymce editor.

I want to be able to show a user the modifications made to the content from one version to another.
The simpler the better, for example, just a green background for added content and a blue background for removed content.

The application is a ruby on rails app and I have full access to my server (slicehost)

Comment: possible duplicate of [diff a ruby string or array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/80091/diff-a-ruby-string-or-array)

Answer (score 2):

You might also look at [differ](http://github.com/pvande/differ).

Answer (score 1):

This might be helpful http://markmcb.com/2008/11/04/ruby-on-rails-diff-text-to-html-ins-and-del/

This uses the diff utility available on most systems and formatting changes would be highlighted as well.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a simple diff program. Here are some good ones:

OSX

FileMerge - Apples own. Installed with XCode

[Changes](http://connectedflow.com/changes/) - Good little app

[Araxis Merge](http://www.araxis.com/merge/index.html) - Commercial but featureful

*Nix

[Meld](http://meld.sourceforge.net/) - Full featured

[Kompare](http://www.caffeinated.me.uk/kompare/) - KDE, very nice

[Gdkdiff](http://directory.fsf.org/project/gtkdiff/) - Simple but effective

[tkdiff](http://directory.fsf.org/project/tkdiff/) - Unkown

simply use the diff command line command...

Win

[Winmerge](http://winmerge.org/) - One of the best