# Example for using diff ruby gem to find difference between two files

Tags: ruby, rubygems, diff

Can someone give me an example to find the difference between two text files in Ruby. I am not able to figure out how to use the `diff` ruby gem. Also it would be great to know how to apply the diff output on the original file and get the latest file. I tried looking at the documentation for `patchr` gem but there was nothing available.

Comment: Have you looked at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3818959/ruby-difference-engine

Comment: possible duplicate of [diff a ruby string or array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/80091/diff-a-ruby-string-or-array)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest that you try [diffy](https://github.com/samg/diffy) instead.