# difflib on Ruby

Tags: python, ruby, string, string-matching, fuzzy-comparison

Is there a library similar to Python's [difflib](http://docs.python.org/library/difflib.html) on Ruby?

Particularly, I need one that has a method similar to [difflib.get_close_matches](http://docs.python.org/library/difflib.html#difflib.get_close_matches). Any recommendations?

Comment: possible duplicate of [diff a ruby string or array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/80091/diff-a-ruby-string-or-array)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research, I suggest using [amatch](http://flori.github.com/amatch/doc/index.html) or [SimMetrics](http://sourceforge.net/projects/simmetrics/) (with JRuby) and manually implement the get_close_matches method. Both libs offer implementations of many string similarity algorithms.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at [diff-lcs](https://rubygems.org/gems/diff-lcs).