# Get difference of arrays in Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [diff a ruby string or array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/80091/diff-a-ruby-string-or-array)

I have an old array: `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`, and new: `[1, 2, 4, 6]`

How to get difference with Ruby: that `5, 3` was removed and `6` was added?

Answer (score 111, accepted):

```
irb(main):001:0> a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
irb(main):002:0> b = [1, 2, 4, 6]
=> [1, 2, 4, 6]
irb(main):003:0> a - b
=> [3, 5]
irb(main):005:0> b - a
=> [6]
irb(main):006:0>
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be great if there was an `Array#diff` or something similar?

Comment: if you want both way difference  `a - b | b - a`

Comment: For one-way diff, also note `a -= b`.

Comment: Notice that it will only work with unique values, if a = [1,1, 2, 3, 4, 5]  you still  get the same [3,5] vs the correct [1,3,5]

Comment: @s1mpl3 : very well noted, `[ 1, 1 ] - [ 1] 
=> []
` ; it does not look a precise definition of difference for arrays; but how do you give a proper definition  of it?  What do you call "correct"?

Comment: @ribamar Seems like it converts arrays to sets, gets the difference and returns the casted array back. This is the reason we don't have array difference in python. If we are sure of no duplicates, python equivalent of this seems: `list (set(a) - set(b))`

Comment: @krozaine: no, it doesn't convert to sets (it would make `Array` to require 'set', which is not a basic ruby structure).  I still find more useful to have one weaker definition than defaulting to "if I don't understand the user, user doesn't know what is doing" style of python. In ruby case, even if removing the duplicates was a decision not obvious to understand, still provides the guarantee of returning  elements in order -- what doesn't necessarily happen in the case of converting to sets (beyond guaranteeing not wasting time with the conversions themselves).

Comment: in ruby 2.6 we have #difference method https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6/Array.html#method-i-difference