# How to extract differing part from many strings?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, ruby-on-rails-3, string

I have many strings. At least 4, max 12. All the Strings have a differing part in the middle. I want to extract the part of the string for each string that differs from all the other strings. How can I practive this?

Comment: Maybe this answers could be helpful to you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/80091/diff-a-ruby-string-or-array

Comment: Example code is help to give very accurate answer to you. Code???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://users.cybercity.dk/~dsl8950/ruby/diff.html

That's all what you need